# How to insert an element at some specific position in the list using classes?

Tags: c++, oop

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    T *values;
    int capacity;
    int counter;
public:
    List()
    {
        values = NULL;
        capacity = 0;
        counter = 0;
    }
    List(int cap)
    {
        capacity = cap;
        values = new T[cap];
        counter = 0;
    }
    bool insert(T item)
    {
        if (isFull() == false)
        {
            values[counter] = item;
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool insertAt(T item, int index)
    {
        
        if (isFull() == false && index < counter)
        {
            capacity++;
            for (int i = capacity; i > index; i--)
                values[i] = values[i - 1];
            
            values[index] = item;
            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool isFull()
    {
        if (counter == capacity)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            cout << values[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    
};
int main()
{
    List<int> obj1(5);
    obj1.insert(1); //0
    obj1.insert(2); //1
    obj1.insert(3); //2
    obj1.insert(4); //3
    
    obj1.insertAt(3, 1);
    obj1.values[1];
    obj1.print();
    
}
```

Kindly look into this program I have to insert an element at given position. But when I run this program I am getting garbage at the end element of an array. Kindly check and let me know where is the problem? Please check the insertAt function I think this function has some logical error. I have added the main function when I call print function it give garbage at the last index

Comment: You should add a simple `main` function that exposes the error you are hunting so people can experiment with the code and be able to see exactly (within allowances for Undefined Behaviour) what you see

Comment: @user4581301 I have edited the question kindly check and let me know where is the problem

Comment: Thank you. Unrelated note: The default constructor doesn't appear to be very useful. Since there is no way to extend the size of the `List` you are stuck, always and forever, with a `List` of size zero.

Comment: A question. On a closer read, I see `insertAt` increased the `capacity` member, not `counter`.  Is this intentional?  Is the goal to increase the size of the array, if so, none of the other infrastructure necessary to allocate a larger array is present. If not, this is possibly where your bug lies.

Comment: Adding this because it seems to be omitted from most programming courses: Take advantage of whatever debugger comes with your development environment. With a debugger you can step through the program line byline and see exactly what the program does as it does it. As soon as you see the program do something you didn't expect, such as store the wrong value or take the wrong path, you've found a mistake. Either it is a bug in the code or a error in your expectations; regardless it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool insertAt(T item, int index)
    {
        
    
        if (!isFull() && index < counter)
        {
            for (int i = counter; i > index; i--) {
                values[i] = values[i - 1];
            }
            values[index] = item;
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            cout << values[i] << " ";
        }
    }
```

I have corrected these two function. Try these functions instead of the one you implemented

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your `insertAt` function:

1. You need to increase `counter`, not `capacity`.  Your `capacity` is fixed at construction time.  It cannot change without allocating a new underlying array and copying the elements over.
2. You also should only run your loop from `counter` to `index` rather than starting at `capacity`, since the elements between `counter` and `capacity` will be uninitialized assuming `T` is a trivial type.
3. You shouldn't set `values[index] = item` until *after* the loop has finished moving all of the existing items.
4. You should `return true` after the loop, and `return false` outside the `if` block

```
bool insertAt(T item, int index)
{
    if (!isFull() && index < counter)
    {
        for (int i = counter; i > index; i--) {
            values[i] = values[i - 1];    
        }
        values[index] = item;
        counter++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: You have a similar mistake in your `print` function.  You're printing all of the values up to `capacity`, but the ones between `counter` and `capacity` are uninitialized.  That loop should also terminate at `counter`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/163e5a345ab1f5c5)

---

It's also worth pointing out that you never `delete[] values`, so that memory will leak when your `list` object dies.  You also haven't followed the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) though, so if you add a destructor that `delete[]`s `values` you'll also need a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator that copy the underlying array so that multiple `list` objects don't try to `delete[]` the same array.

Comment: I have folllowed what you said but now it is inserting at the right position but in the last index value is 4 not 5

Comment: @OmegaCoding Note: I made a mistake; see my latest edit.  The extra `- 1` is not needed and the loop should not be inclusive of `index`, since you're moving from items from `values[i - 1]` to `values[i]`.

Comment: I have checked the updated one still las t element is missing:(\

Comment: @OmegaCoding It [works fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/163e5a345ab1f5c5).  There was also a bug in your `print` function that I added a note about.